# How many fields to INCLUDE on a SQL index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table with millions of rows

```
+----+----------+-----------+--------+-------+-------------+------------------+
| ID | ClientID | ProjectID | Status | Note  | AccountOwner| + 7 more fields  |
+----+----------+-----------+--------+-------+-------------+------------------+
```

with indexes on ID (clusted) and ClientID (non-clustered)

I'm trying to reduce execution time using INCLUDE columns on the ClientID index. I have several queries for this table but two common ones are:

```
SELECT ID, ClientID, ProjectID, Status WHERE ClientID = 4987
```

and

```
SELECT ID, ClientID, AccountOwner, + 5 more fields WHERE ClientID = 4987
```

In order to use the INCLUDE feature to cover both queries, I would need to include 8 or 9 fields on the ClientID index.

In testing, it reduces the query time from 20 secs down to 2 so the feature seems to be what I need.

The problem I have is that it feels like this may be too many fields but seems necessary to cover both common use cases and I do not know enough about how it works internally to know if this is a good idea or not. Is this too many fields? Is there another feature to use or a way to test and see the impact of having so many fields on the INCLUDE?

Edit: I'm not asking about creating an index on two fields, I'm asking about using the "Include columns" feature of an index (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx)

Comment: The only thing you are searching here is ClientID.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes but retrieving the other data on the table is causing another lookup and slowing me down

Answer (score 1):

The index will be bigger, taking a bit longer to search (as not as much of the index can be stored on 1 page), take up more storage space, take up more memory when searching, need more updating when someone updates a record.

If you have 2 very common searches then the alternative is to have 2 indexes 1 for each use case. This will probably take up more storage space, but reduce the search time (possibly immeasurably depending on the size of the table). Each index would take up less space on the disk and in memory, but combined would probably take up more. Inserting a record or Updating the ClientID column in the table would take longer as both indexes would possibly need to be updated.

Personlly, I'd go with the 1 index that covered both queries.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that he is talking about de Include feature of the index, and this feature is for the fields in the select. I understand your situation. I have face the same problem in the past. You have to make your own test to see wich scenario best fit your needs. You can create an index by ClientID including the rest of the fields and will make your query a lot faster. But the index will be huge and take a lot of disk space. In this case i strongly suggest to Split your index and data on different filegroups if posible different fisical disk. I'm my scenario using include on index make my query a lot faster but in the other hand, 70% of the space used by the database in on the indexes. Is your choice.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, both queries uses the same column ClientID in the where clause.  One index INLCUDE only ClientId should be sufficient for both. Index based on the columns in the where clause not select caluse.

Comment: I'm not asking about creating an index on two fields, I'm asking about using the "Include columns" feature of an index (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx)

Comment: He is not asking about the field to index by. The question is about the fields on the INCLUDE predicate and in this case are the fields in the SELECT